# Alternating Series Estimation Theorem and this series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> $$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^6}$$
> With the error being $\vert \mathbf{error} \vert \lt \ .00005$

In order for the series to undergo the **Alternating Series Estimation Theorem**

According to the James Stewart Textbook Essential Calculus Early Transcendentals Second Edition states that the theorem goes like this:

### Theorem

> If $s = \sum (-1)^{n-1}b_n$ is the sum of the an alternating series that satisfies
> $$(\mathbf{i})\ \ \ \ 0 \le b_{n+1} \le b_n \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\mathbf{ii}) \ \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$$
> then
> $$\vert R_n \vert = \vert s - s_n \vert \le b_{n+1}$$

My first step was then to verify the first condition which was then as follows:

> $$b_n = \frac{1}{n^6}$$
> $$b_{n+1} = \frac{1}{(n+1)^6}$$
> $$0 \le \frac{1}{(n+1)^6} \le \frac{1}{n^6}$$

Which proved out to be true in this case. From there I went for the second condition and verified the limit.
$$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^6}= 0$$

Afterwards from verifying these two conditions I then began the procedure to find the error.
$$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^6}= 1 - \frac{1}{64}+ \frac{1}{729} - \frac{1}{4096}+ \frac{1}{15625} - \frac{1}{46656}$$

At this term the error turns out to be:
$$b_6 \lt .00005$$
$$.00002 \lt .00005$$

Therefore I concluded this statement:

> $$\vert R_5 \vert = \vert s - s_5 \vert \le b_6$$
> Boiling it down to the following:
> $\vert s - 0.98557 \vert \le .00002$
> From here I get a bit lost with absolute value but using Wolfram Alpha [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28-1%29%5E%28j%2B1%29%2Fj%5E6%2C%20j%3D1..infinity). If I break that absolute value and add the $s_5$ to both sides I get the approximation is that right? Or because I would have to split the inequality into a positive and negative side?

Comment: $\lvert s-0.98577\rvert\le -0.00002$ doesn't make sense, both as a standalone sentence and as a part of the current discussion: keep in mind that the $b_n$ in the theorem you are using are non-negative.

Comment: @Gae.S. Even if one were to solving for s?

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky If you want to solve for $s$, you obtain $s\in\emptyset$.

Comment: For an alternating series $s=\sum_n (-1)^{n+1} b_n$ then $\vert s - s_n \vert \le b_{n+1}$ is correct, thus $s\in [s_n-b_{n+1},s_n+b_{n+1}]$, looking at the sign you can improve to $s\in (s_n,s_n+b_{n+1})$ for $n$ even, finally for this particular series you can show the asymptotic $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{s-s_{2n}}{2 (2n)^6}=1$ (a more precise asymptotic for $s-s_{2n}$ is given by the Bernouilli numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is right, though it is not really mentioned why you chose to stop there. Note that we have:

$$\frac1{n^6}<0.00005\iff n^6>20000\iff n>\sqrt[6]{20000}\simeq5.2$$

Hence taking the 6th term as the error term would have sufficed.

Without absolute value bars, we have:

$$0.98555\le s\le0.98559$$

As a sidenote, the actual value is given by:

$$s=0.98555109\dots$$

and that only 4 terms are required for the desired accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually, we can get the accurate result of the series sum.
$$\text{First, we should know that }\zeta(6)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^6}=\dfrac{\pi^6}{945}$$
$$\text{Denote }A=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^6}, B= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(2n)^6}\text{ ,where $A$,$B$ are convegent.}$$
Since $$A+B=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^6}=\dfrac{\pi^6}{945}$$
$$B=\dfrac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^6}}{64}=\dfrac{\pi^6}{60480}$$
$$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^6}=A+B-2B=\dfrac{31\pi^6}{30240}$$