# Is expanding via Taylor series true only for values less than 1 ??

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation

How do I prove this result??

prove $1+x/2-x^3/8<(1+x)^{1/2}$    , for $x>0$

And while we're at it, I had a deeper doubt, Is expanding via Taylor series true only for ,
$x<1$ ?

Because, we easily write the error term as the smallest power of x that is not in the expansion i.e if we expand upto $n^\text{th}$ power, we take error term as  $(x-a)^{n+1}*f^{(n+1)thderivative}(a)$$/(n+1)!$   , which would only be true if $x<1$ otherwise the most significant term should be the last term in the series which would tend to infinity for $x>1$.

This doubt arises because I have used Maclaurin series several times and there we always take $x$ tending to zero

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right in this case. The value of a Taylor series (or power series in general) may not be defined at some region since the value will go wild. A concept called [Radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) is there to determine how far can a power series converge.

See for example, the solution of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802024/determine-the-taylor-series-for-fx-x3-cdot-ln-sqrtx-around-the-poin?rq=1) to find out how to calculate the radius of convergence.

Comment: Is this concept of Radius of convergence, for one variable same as defining a condition like    modulus(x-a) <= r       which is a condition usually given when we need to calculate the error ?

Comment: @user14812745 Well RoC is telling you how large can a sequence converge before blowing up, the condition like that is just usually telling you how you can bound the error within the range.

Answer (score 1):

For the first result, the formula in the question appears to be in error.
I think you are supposed to use the Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^{1/2},$
which is
$$ (1+x)^{1/2} = 1 + \frac12 x - \frac18 x^2 + - \cdots $$
(continuing with alternating $+$ and $-$ signs). Note that it's $\frac18 x^2$ rather than $\frac18 x^3,$ suggesting that there's a typo in the question.
(Did you check carefully after copying the formulas?)

For $0 < x \leq 1$ this is a convergent alternating series and you can apply the Alternating Series Estimation Theorem.
(For a theorem statement and example, see [Alternating Series Estimation Theorem and this series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3488535/139123).)

For $x < 0$ the result you're supposed to prove is false.

For $x > 1$ the result is true but the Taylor series around $0$ does not converge.
There are other methods you could apply, such as squaring the quantities on both sides when $1 + \frac12 x - \frac18 x^2$ is positive.

It depends on exactly what you were supposed to prove--that is, for which $x$ you were supposed to prove the inequality.

---

As for Taylor series for $x > 1,$ consider a polynomial such as
$p(x) = 1 + x + 3x^2 - 4x^3.$
The formula for this polynomial is literally its own Taylor series,
with zero coefficients for the $x^4$ term and all higher terms
(because the $4$th derivative of this polynomial is zero).
The Taylor series is good for any real number $x.$

Now consider the Taylor series around $0$ for
$$f(x) = \frac1{1+x} = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 +- \cdots .$$
This converges for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$ and
diverges for $\lvert x\rvert > 1$.

But now look at
$$g(x) = \frac1{1+2x} = 1 - 2x + 4x^2 - 8x^3 +- \cdots .$$
This diverges for $\lvert x\rvert > \frac12$.

On the other hand,
$$g(x) = \frac1{1+\frac12x} = 1 - \frac12x + \frac14x^2 - \frac18x^3 +- \cdots $$
converges for $\lvert x\rvert < 2$.

So in the case of a Taylor series around $0,$
the limit on $\lvert x\rvert$ does not have to be $1.$
It could be any number.

For any particular Taylor series centered at $a$, if there is a number $r$ for which the series converges whenever $\lvert x - a\rvert < r$
and diverges whenever $\lvert x - a\rvert > r$,
we say that $r$ is the *radius of convergence* of the series.
If the series converges for all real $x$, we say the radius of convergence is infinite.

Comment: thanks for the extensive answer, so in my question, I will have radius of convergence as 1 and hence can't use taylor series beyond it??

Comment: For the series that those terms came from, yes. Yves Daoust mentioned the intuitive reason: at $x = -1$ the expression $(1 + x)^{1/2}$ blows up.

Comment: Could you tell the " fact about alternating series" you mentioned ??     I still can't understand how to solve the exact question.

Comment: @user14812745 The inequality is *false* as Raffaele's answer points out. Did you have any restrictions on the domain you are proving?

Comment: @macton I assumed there was a typo in the question and worked on the "corrected" question instead, with $x^2$ rather than $x^3.$

Comment: @DavidK The question states to prove this result for $x>0$ only

Answer (score 0):

Convergence of a Taylor series depends on how fast the coefficients decrease. For example

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots$$

they decrease so fast that the series converges for any $x$.

In general, the series converges up to the closest singularity of the function. For instance,

$$\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$$ cannot converge past $x=1$ because the function goes to infinity.

But obviously, by a simple rescaling

$$\frac1{1-2x}=1+2x+4x^2+8x^3+\cdots$$ converges up to $x=\dfrac12$, while

$$\frac3{3-x}=1+\frac x3+\frac{x^2}9+\frac{x^3}{27}+\cdots$$ converges up to $x=3$.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality
$$1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^3}{8}<\sqrt{x+1}$$
is false, in general.

It is true for $x>\alpha$ where $\alpha\approx 0.743014$ is the largest root of
$$1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^3}{8}-\sqrt{x+1}=0$$
(see picture below)

[image]